# Take an integral of $\tan x$ and $\sec x$ to a power of something without using reduction formula?

Tags: integration

Assume $p>1$ is a positive integer.

Can I take the integral of $\tan^{p}x$ without using reduction formula?

The same applied to $\sec^{p}x$

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by reduction formula? Do you mean integration by parts? :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $p$ is odd:
$$\int\tan^p(x)dx = \int\frac{\sin^p(x)}{\cos^p(x)}dx = \int\frac{[\sin^2(x)]^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}{\cos^p(x)}\sin(x)dx = \int\frac{[1 - \cos^2(x)]^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}{\cos^p(x)}\sin(x)dx$$

Then we substitute $u = \cos(x), du = -\sin(x) dx$

$$-\int\frac{[1 - u^2]^\frac{p - 1}{2}}{u^p}du$$

Which can be solved by expanding out the numerator and dividing out the denominator.

---

Let's say $p$ is even:

$$\int\tan^p(x)dx = \int\tan^{p-2}(x)\tan^2(x)dx =\int\tan^{p-2}(x)[\sec^2(x) - 1]dx$$
Which is then handled by distributing the $\tan$, and breaking it up into two integrals. One of the integrals is easy with the substitution $u = tan(x), du = sec^2(x) dx$, but the other integral will be another $tan^p(x)$ which needs to have this process done onto it again.

---

For this next case, let's say p is even:

$$\int\sec^p(x) dx = \int\sec^2(x)[\sec^2(x)]^\frac{p-2}{2}dx = \int\sec^2(x)[1 + \tan^2(x)]^\frac{p-2}{2}dx$$

Substitute $u = \tan(x), du = \sec^2(x)dx$

$$\int(1 + u^2)^\frac{p-2}{2} du$$
Which is solved by expanding the binomial.

---

For any case of $p$, you can take $sec^2(x)$ out, then integrate by parts. There will be a $tan^2(x)$ inside the the integral, turn that into $sec^2 - 1$ then distribute. Now, you will have $\int sec^p(x) dx$ on both sides of the integral, collect and solve. This leads to the general form of the integral:

$$\int\sec^p(x)dx = \frac{sec^{p-2}(x)\tan(x) + (p-2)\int\sec^{p-2}(x)dx}{p-1}$$

As stated above, this works for all p. So, this is useful to knock out the odd ones.